Issues with Skywalking receiving monitoring data from OpenTelemetry Collector due to connection failures
Issues with Skywalking receiving monitoring data from OpenTelemetry Collector due to connection failures
2024-08-05T15:43:15.935+0800    warn    zapgrpc/zapgrpc.go:193  [core] [Channel #1 SubChannel #2]grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {Addr: "[::1]:11800", ServerName: "localhost:11800", }. Err: connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing: dial tcp [::1]:11800: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it."       {"grpc_log": true}
2024-08-05T15:43:15.936+0800    warn    zapgrpc/zapgrpc.go:193  [core] [Channel #1 SubChannel #2]grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {Addr: "127.0.0.1:11800", ServerName: "localhost:11800", }. Err: connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:11800: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it."       {"grpc_log": true}
2024-08-05T15:43:18.148+0800    info    exporterhelper/retry_sender.go:118      Exporting failed. Will retry the request after interval.        {"kind": "exporter", "data_type": "metrics", "name": "otlp", "error": "rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection error: desc = \"transport: Error while dialing: dial tcp [::1]:11800: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.\"", "interval": "13.117546978s"}
2024-08-05T15:43:19.460+0800    info    exporterhelper/retry_sender.go:118      Exporting failed. Will retry the request after interval.        {"kind": "exporter", "data_type": "metrics", "name": "otlp", "error": "rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection error: desc = \"transport: Error while dialing: dial tcp [::1]:11800: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.\"", "interval": "4.343289865s"}
2024-08-05T15:43:23.028+0800    info    exporterhelper/retry_sender.go:118      Exporting failed. Will retry the request after interval.        {"kind": "exporter", "data_type": "metrics", "name": "otlp", "error": "rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection error: desc = \"transport: Error while dialing: dial tcp [::1]:11800: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.\"", "interval": "17.645745744s"}
2024-08-05T15:43:23.810+0800    info    exporterhelper/retry_sender.go:118      Exporting failed. Will retry the request after interval.        {"kind": "exporter", "data_type": "metrics", "name": "otlp", "error": "rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection error: desc = \"transport: Error while dialing: dial tcp [::1]:11800: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.\"", "interval": "9.737238814s"}

However, Skywalking is already listening on port 11800.
curl http://localhost:11800
curl: (1) Received HTTP/0.9 when not allowed

i wish that skywalking can receive the data from otel, and then it can show on the ui.
